# Likelihood field sensor model (Probabilistic Robotics, Thrun et al., p.169-174)

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, wheeled-robot, algorithm

I am currently working on the "likelihood field" sensor model (aka "endpoint model") by Thrun et al. (book: Probabilistic Robotics, Thrun et al., p.169-174)
In this context I have two questions. According to the authors, the probability of a sensor measurement $z_{t}^{k}$ can be described by a weighted set consisting of $p_{hit}$, $p_{rand}$ and $p_{max}$ (mixing weights $z_{hit}$, $z_{rand}$, $z_{max}$):

[image: Probabilistic Robotics, Thrun et al., p.171]

In the following, the authors describe that the implementation of the likelihood field algorithm (see below) does not take $z_{max}$ measurements into account.

Question 1: If $z_{max}$ measurements are rejected, what is the intention of the probability $p_{max}$ in equation (6.34)?

My second question refers to line 8 of the following algorithm:

[image: Probabilistic Robotics, TRHUN et al., p.172]

Note errata : replace "$z_{random}$" by "$z_{rand}$"
(http://probabilistic-robotics.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/errata.html)

What is the meaning of the second term $\frac{zrand}{zmax}$? Does $z_{rand}$ describe the weight factor of the uniform distribution $p_{rand} = \frac{1}{z_{max}}$? In this context, $z_{max}$ describes the maximum range of the laser scanner and not a weight factor...

Thanks for your help.